# Data from WebApi to sql database

Tags: c#, sql

I get Invoices from a WebApi and I insert these Invoices into a SQL table.
I use C# to do this operation.
I use System.Data.SqlClient where I generate this SQL query:

```
string sql = String.Format("insert into [dbo].[InvoiceHeader] values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')", inv.logNo, inv.locationCode, inv.invSeq,inv.reference);

command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem is that one of the Invoices has an inv.reference = "Box 20' Cont" and that ' is a problem for the InsertCommand. How do I insert text into a sql database when the variable contains an ' in the text?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch to using parameters. This will make your code safer and cases like the one your question is about will resolve quite easy:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "insert into [dbo].[InvoiceHeader] values (@logoNo,@locationCode,@ref)", conn);

SqlParameter param1  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@logoNo";
param.Value         = inv.logNo;

SqlParameter param2  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@locationCode";
param.Value         = inv.locationCode;

SqlParameter param3  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@ref";
param.Value         = inv.invSeq,inv.reference;

cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);
```

All the necessary quoting and protection against SQL-injection will be taken care of. You still need to handle exceptions and general errors.

Comment: I tried to use this approach but I got an error.
What do I do when one of the parameters is Null?

Comment: That depends on your table/column definition. If NULL is not allowed for a column, then the parameters can't be NULL. Your previous method must have run into the same problem.

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it clearer how to go about it. Have you added the parameters to your command before?

Answer (score -1):

It was actually easy.

I just did it like this.

inv.reference.Replace("'", "''")

Worked like a charm